# How can I access Jenkins credentials in pipeline without getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've created Jenkins credentials called `GITHUB_TOKEN` for my pipeline. I'm accessing that credentials from below code of my pipeline.

```
def downloadGitAssets(String owner, String repo_name, String tag, String assert_name) {
    dir("scripts") {
        withGithubCredentials(GITHUB_TOKEN){
            return sh(
                    script: "./git_assets_download.sh ${GITHUB_TOKEN} ${owner} ${repo_name} ${tag} ${assert_name}",
                    returnStdout: true,
            ).trim()
        }
    }
}

def withGithubCredentials(credentialsId, body) {
    withCredentials([
            string(
                    credentialsId: credentialsId,
                    variable: "GITHUB_TOKEN"
            ),
    ]) {
        body()
    }
}
```

But I'm getting below exception during the run. How can I resolve it?

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GITHUB_TOKEN for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:355)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:355)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.downloadGitAssets(WorkflowScript:402)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor450.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: “credentialsId: credentialsId” seems incorrect to me. On the right side, you would need to replace the unique id of the credentials holding GITHUB_TOKEN. If GITHUB_TOKEN is the id, you gotta mention that

Comment: @harshavmb here ```credentialsId``` is a parameter of ```def withGithubCredentials(credentialsId, body)``` function. Therefore I'm passing credentila ID in the above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed on '' credentialsId

should be like this

`withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'YOUR_CREDENTIAL_ID', variable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN')]` and after that access the token inside any command using `$GITHUB_TOKEN`.

OR another approach would be include the the credentials in environment section like this

```
pipeline {
  environment {

    GITHUB_TOKEN = credentials('YOUR_CREDENTIAL_ID')

  }
}
```

And access anywhere the `$GITHUB_TOKEN` anywhere in jenkisnfile and if you use this approch then I guess you don't also need this function `def withGithubCredentials(credentialsId, body)`

So you can use it like this

```
pipeline {
  environment {

    GITHUB_TOKEN = credentials('YOUR_CREDENTIAL_ID')

  }
}


def downloadGitAssets(String owner, String repo_name, String tag, String assert_name) {
    dir("scripts") {
        withGithubCredentials(body){
            return sh(
                    script: "./git_assets_download.sh ${GITHUB_TOKEN} ${owner} ${repo_name} ${tag} ${assert_name}",
                    returnStdout: true,
            ).trim()
        }
    }
}

def withGithubCredentials(body) {
    withCredentials([
            string(
                    credentialsId: 'YOUR_CREDENTIAL_ID',
                    variable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN'
            ),
    ]) {
        body()
    }
}
```